# Spark zero bytesWritten using SQLServerBulkCopy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save a dataframe into a sql database using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.
The code does the work and inserts some rows into my table, but when I look at the OutputMetric.BytesWritten, the value is 0. Did I miss anything?

```
  val fileRecord = new SQLServerBulkDataFrameFileRecord(iterator, bulkCopyMetadata)
  val sqlServerBulkCopy = new SQLServerBulkCopy(connection)
  sqlServerBulkCopy.setDestinationTableName(dbTable)
  sqlServerBulkCopy.setBulkCopyOptions(BulkCopyUtils.getBulkCopyOptions(config))
  sqlServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(fileRecord)
```

[stage result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9JAf.png)

[task result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCAdd.png)